# The right way to return [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

Here is the program to return `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`

```python
[[0]*3,[0,1,0],[0]*3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6faBvzPzraIFbLWCfaQMdQxyBWB8yL/V9QlJlXopGo@R8A)

Can you shorten this code?

Comment: I believe this is the shortest possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because I don't believe it meets the standard of effort required of tips questions. From [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18613/92901): 'Simply dumping code and saying "How can this be shorter?" is not acceptable. The poster needs to state things they've tried or point out specific parts they think could be improved.'

Comment: @Dingus I really need this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 20 bytes

```python
[b:=[0]*3,[0,1,0],b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfaBvzPzrJyjbaIFbLWCfaQMdQxyBWJyn2f0FRZl6JRqLmfwA) Note that modifying the first subarray also modifies the third subarray, so this would not be suitable in that case.

Comment: i was 6 hours late! cuz of timezone ...